# How do I get the column name from an Entity Framework Association

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have an entity model built using the designer. In one of my tables (application), I have several foreign keys that reference the same status (status) table. As a result, when my associations were built, I have several entity objects built with an auto indexing name:

- application_statuses2
- application_statuses3

etc.

I'm building a "version history" type screen and want to be able to properly list the "friendly name" for each column modified. For example, I want to display "Destination Status" will be displayed instead of "application_statuses2". If I can determine the endpoint column name on the association in question, I can setup the proper display value.

I can find the entity object in the designer, I can even track where it references the foreign key in question that built the association, but I can seem to find the property that outlines the enpoints or column names. How do I determine the column name, or endpoint, on my association, or entity?

Answer (score 2):

I wish it were more ready to hand, have been looking for it as well. Bit of a pain when you have multiple FKs to the same table.

1. Click on the navigation property you want to check
2. Under properties, look at the name of the association
3. At the top of properties, use the object navigator dropdown to switch to the association
4. Click into the 'Referential Constraint' property
5. Use the ellipses button on the right to bring up the column names

Dont know if there is a better way of doing this, but I certainly hope so!

Comment: I was able to find this, but I'm looking for a way to do it programmatically. I was able to take a different route and provide unique names for my endpoints and work that way, but I'm sure there's another way.

Comment: ok, would it not be easier just changing the property name through the designer? You can then refer to it how you want in the model

Comment: if you are looking for a way to control the way its generated in the first place, this article may be worth a gander [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I wound up going back into the endpoints and renaming them so I could better tell which one I was dealing with. That's probably the best way too to help avoid confusion.